# How to merge info in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql database with 2 tables: `users` and `logins`. `users` table contains user info and `logins` table contains the contact login ids through which user can sign in. These login ids are either email or phone number. These login ids act as public ids. `userId` is never given out in the results.

Now I am trying to create a stored procedure which gives list (see `tempTable`) of all the users with their phone number and email.

[image: db model]

I have written the following procedure so far:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable (
public_id varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
info1 varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
info2 varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
info3 varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
phone varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
email varchar(255) DEFAULT ''
);

insert into tempTable(public_id, info1, info2, info3 ) (select userid, info1, info2, info3 from users);

Update tempTable
Inner Join logins
On tempTable.public_id = logins.userid
Set
tempTable.public_id = logins.login_id;
```

This is able to change the `pulic_id` of `tempTable` to the `login_id` of `logins` table. But now, how do I put phone and email into the `tempTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Code As follows:

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable (
    public_id varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    info1 varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    info2 varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    info3 varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    phone varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    email varchar(255) DEFAULT ''
    );

    insert into tempTable(public_id, info1, info2, info3 ) (select userid, info1, info2, info3 from users);

    Update tempTable
    Inner Join logins
    On tempTable.public_id = logins.userid
    Set
    tempTable.public_id = logins.login_id,
    tempTable.email = logins.login_id
    Where logins.login_type = 'email';

    Update tempTable
    Inner Join logins
    On tempTable.public_id = logins.userid
    Set
    tempTable.public_id = logins.login_id,
    tempTable.mobile = logins.login_id
    Where logins.login_type = 'mobile';
```